# How to fix this command mass renaming files to match a text file

Tags: command-line, files, fedora, rename

```
for file in *; do read line;  mv -v "${file}" "${line}";  done < /var/www/html/uploads/songs.txt
```

It works as in changing all 700 files. But it doesn't seem to do it in the correct order. I feel like it's changing the order as it renames them or something I'm not 100% sure.

Here is an example:
First File is:

```
/var/www/html/uploads/Music/A.D.I.D.A_S - Live (Korn Live).mp3_Rare_2006_.mp3
```

First in the text file that it should be renamed to:

```
/var/www/html/uploads/Music/A_D_I_D_A_S__Live_Korn_Live__.mp3_Rare_2006_.mp3
```

Like I said all of them get renamed and a lot of them match. Typically the first and last few. The middle however seems to not stay in the appropriate order and end up getting another files name.

Comment: `ls * >list.txt` will produce a list of the file in the order in which they will be processed (because the '*' will be expanded exactly in the same way as in your command). Does this match your file?

Comment: What's the significance of `/var/www/html/uploads/songs.txt`? It looks as if you just want to modify the existing filename by translating  some punctuation characters...

Comment: I'm voting to close this as unclear until such time that further information is added regarding the contents of the file that you read.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO a very dangerous technique, you are at the mercy of any change in the directory  (files added/deleted). A much safer technique is to list pairs of old/new names, and either:

- iterate the existing files, using `grep` to retrieve the new name
- load the whole list in an associative array (in recent version of bash, arrays can use string indices)
- forego all that complexity, just add `mv`` at the beginning of lines in the list, and use it as a script

You can generate the list of pairs using:

```
ls pattern_for_old* | paste - list_of_new_names >combined.lst
```

(incidentally, just generating this list can show you where your current problem is...)